# Matplotlib contourf with 3 colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a contour plot with 3 distinct colors. So far, my code looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xMin = 0
xMax = 3
xList = np.linspace(xMin, xMax, 10)
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(xList, xList)
Z = []
# do some processing with Z
# Z now contains 0, 0.5 or 1, e.g. Z = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.5...]
Z = Z.reshape((len(X1), len(X2)))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, Z,alpha=0.5)
```

Now I'd like to plot every contour where Z = 0 as red, Z = 0.5 as green and Z = 1 as blue. I do not want to have smooth transitions between red/green/blue, but just a color switch.
I played around with the color and levels option, but it did not really work out as expected.

Is the contour plot the right way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the colors of a contour plot with the colors option but you might want to use imshow to avoid interpolation between the levels. You create a colormap for imshow with discrete levels using [ListedColormap](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap).

```
data = 0*np.ones((20,20))
data[5:15,5:15] = 0.5
data[7:12,8:16] = 1

# contourf plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax1.contourf(data, [0,0.4,0.9], colors = ['r','g','b']) 
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.set_title('contourf')

# imshow plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
# define colr map
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['r','g','b'])
bounds = [0, 0.4,0.6, 1.1]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

ax2.imshow(data, interpolation = 'none', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
ax2.set_title('imshow')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking for